# How to allow more than one registered user to have the same email?

Tags: user-registration

How can I allow a user to register on the site and ignore the error WP throws back if email is already registered  - "This email is already registered, please choose another one."

I tried writing my own plugin but it isn't working:

```
if($errors['field'.$field->id] == 'This email is already registered, please choose another one.')
unset($errors['field'.$field->id]);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

PS.

i) I know its not ideal to allow same email for registration but can't see another solution to allow same family members to register under different usernames but same family email.

ii) The answer on a previous question did not work on single site, using the code

```
add_filter('pre_user_email', 'skip_email_exist');
```

this is why I had to ask this question for single site solution.

Comment: And when someone wants to reset their password...?

Comment: @webaware I have heard that email is sent to first user email, which is a sacrifice I am willing to make since it is assumed that it is the same user on all accounts....

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125127/changing-username-after-registration-to-get-around-the-issue-of-having-duplicate/125129#125129)? But you still have to take care of the password reset ... maybe only allow password recovery via username and not email?

Comment: You probably need to have custom registration functionality to bypass this email check for existing user. Do you already have such code?

Answer (score 4):

So unfortunately without major revisions to both code and database structure this is not possible because WordPress stores the user email in a "UNIQUE" row in the database. Just unsetting the error message will not solve this issue because the user does not get created.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already looked at `wp-includes/user.php`, which I'm referring to below

Simplest way: Comment out Line 1691 ( `EDIT : THIS METHOD IS NOT RECOMMENDED AS  IT'S EDITING CORE FILES AND ISN'T FUTURE-PROOF AND SHOULD BE CONSIDERED A LAST RESORT`)

Alternative way: 
Line 1690 users.php has the following:

```
elseif ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'email_exists', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email is already registered, please choose another one.' ) );
    }
```

In your code example, you are using `$errors['field'.$field->id]`
Have you checked to see if `$errors['field'.$field->id]` exists/is set?
Not sure of correct syntax to use here, but you could check for, then unset something like `$errors['email_exists']`

HTH

Comment: Changing core files is not recommended ...

Comment: Agreed - but as this sounds like it could be a family website, I thought I'd give the OP an option.

Comment: ps: we also have to keep in mind that your answer will probably be read by many other users looking for a solution to a similar problem and they might start editing core files to solve it ;-)